# Control's size does not update with autosize set to true

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, autosize

I have a little `fsStayOnTop` style form that I use as a busy screen in a tool I am developing. I have a TLabel control on the form, which displays what exactly the app is doing (or, why it is busy) at that moment.

Before I start something that might take long, I update the caption of the TLabel control and try to resize the form to nicely fit the text in the middle. The TLabel control has its autosize property set to true.

The code is like this.

```
procedure TfrmBusy.SetText(txt: String);
begin
  m_lblText.caption:= txt;
  self.width = m_lblText.left + m_lblText.width + 64;
  self.height = m_lblText.top + m_lblText.height + 64;
end;
```

Then I show the form using frmBusy.Show.

But the form does not get rendered in the expected size.

It seems that there is a delay for the size to get updated automatically, and as such, the size would be reflected the next time I show the busy form if I set the text to the same thing as before (which does not cause the label to change its size).

Is there anyway to make this instantaneous so that I can use the correct width/height of the label in calculation of the form's width/height? If not, what are my options?

Edit: This is on Windows and with Lazarus 1.6/FPC 3.0.0.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: What I typically do is: 1) Make the form wide enough to display the largest label text width. 2) Center the label  in the form. 3) Set the Label.Alignment to `alCenter`, and .AutoSize to True.

Comment: @Ken White 
I thought of this too. It is not perfect, but it would work.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Lazarus trunk

Comment: Another alternative is to size your form to the max width you want it to be, drop the label on the form, size it to the width and height of the form, turn AutoSize off and WordWrap on.